# How can I specify that the value of a variable in VBscript be case insensitive?

Tags: vbscript

Part of a VBscript I'm writing inside of an HTA calls for the user to type a name into a text box which will generate a folder with that name. I am building checks into the script to make sure that no illegal characters or names are used. Where I am getting stuck at is trying to make sure that if a user enters COM1 or LPT1 they will be told that the name they tried to use is not allowed instead of getting a script error. The problem is I can't figure out how to do it without writing an If statement for every possible way the letters in COM1 through COM9 and LPT1 through LPT9 could be arranged in different cases (e.g. com1, Com1, cOm1, etc.). The code snippet below shows what I mean.

```
sFldrName = BasicTextbox.Value
sFldrBadMsg = "You've chosen an illegal folder name."

If sFldrname = "COM1" Then
  Msgbox  sFldrBadMsg
ElseIf sFldrname = "COM2" Then
  Msgbox  sFldrBadMsg
ElseIf sFldrname = "COM3" Then
  Msgbox  sFldrBadMsg
```

In the above example whatever the user enters into the text box is assigned to "sFldrname". Then the script checks whether the string assigned "sFldrname" is COM1 or COM2 or COM3. The problem is I can only check for those strings in the exact case specified. If the user enters COM1 they will get my warning message. But, if they enter com1 (all lower case) or CoM1 (mixed case) they will get a script error because it is still an illegal name regardless of case. In order to account for this with the method I used above I would have to do something like this:

```
sFldrName = BasicTextbox.Value
sFldrBadMsg = "You've chosen an illegal folder name."

If sFldrname = "COM1" Then
  Msgbox  sFldrBadMsg
ElseIf sFldrname = "Com1" Then
  Msgbox  sFldrBadMsg
ElseIf sFldrname = "COm1" Then
  Msgbox  sFldrBadMsg
ElseIf sFldrname = "cOm1" Then
  Msgbox  sFldrBadMsg
ElseIf sFldrname = "coM1" Then
  Msgbox  sFldrBadMsg
ElseIf sFldrname = "cOM1" Then
  Msgbox  sFldrBadMsg
ElseIf sFldrname = "CoM1" Then
  Msgbox  sFldrBadMsg
ElseIf sFldrname = "com1" Then
  Msgbox  sFldrBadMsg
```

And I would have to do that for COM2 through COM9 and LPT1 through LPT9 as well. I really don't want to have to do that. So, when I am checking the value of "sFldrname" to see what string it is, is there a way to ignore the case of that string? Or, is there a better way altogether to go about doing what I am trying to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonical way, as others have already mentioned, is to uppercase (or lowercase) the value of the variable you want to compare:

```
If LCase(sFldrname) = "com1" Then
  Msgbox  sFldrBadMsg
ElseIf LCase(sFldrname) = "com2" Then
  Msgbox  sFldrBadMsg
ElseIf LCase(sFldrname) = "com3" Then
  Msgbox  sFldrBadMsg
End If
```

Using the [`StrComp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya4w6fwy%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) function would be another option:

```
If StrComp(sFldrname, "COM1", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
  Msgbox  sFldrBadMsg
ElseIf StrComp(sFldrname, "COM2", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
  Msgbox  sFldrBadMsg
ElseIf StrComp(sFldrname, "COM3", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
  Msgbox  sFldrBadMsg
End If
```

However, since you're doing an n-way comparison of the same variable, your best choice would probably be a [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ef9w614%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) statement in combination with `UCase` or `LCase`:

```
Select Case UCase(sFldrname)
  Case "COM1", "COM2", "COM3" : MsgBox sFldrBadMsg
  Case Else : MsgBox "OK"
End Select
```

Comment: I like the Select Case method. The problem is if an illegal name like COM1 is entered, after my warning message appears and is acknowledged, the script continues to run and move on to the point later in the code where the folder is created. So immediately after I click OK on the message box with the warning about the illegal folder name I get a the same script error I would normally get for an illegal folder name. I need some way to stop the script once OK in the message box is clicked. Any ideas?

Comment: Derp! I realized that all I needed to do is add "Exit Sub" on a line before "End Select" and it works the way I was asking about. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: I am not against this answer jkolb, but you need to consider what you are writing here.  If you do this, then you have to be able to match from COM1, to COM...Anything really.  And same for LPT.  You are going to suffer from what we call "Code Bloat".  Please consider the solutions I've offered you with RegEx, as it handles everything in ONE shot.  ONE test, resulting in faster code, and more reliable code...  If you want a way to call a function, or perform some sort of test, and be able to execute something like a Perl "or die" operator, I can show you that in another answer/question.

Comment: I commented on your solution below. Check it out and give me some feedback.

Comment: @LarryF it's a [rather finite list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx), so that's not really an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do something like:

```
If UCase(sFldrname) = "COM1" Then
  Msgbox  sFldrBadMsg
end if
```

That will uppercase your string, and then you can just compare the results with all uppercase.  You are better off probably just looking for COM, and a colon.  Now, for the BEST possible security,. and assurance that a path is correct, you want to look into something a little more serious, like Regular Expressions.  Regular Expression can take the users input and test it for a valid "Path like" string.

Something like:

```
Dim RegEx, bFound
Set RegEx = New RegExp
RegEx.IgnoreCase = True
RegEx.Pattern = "^(?:\b((?#drive)[a-z]):\\((?#folder)[^/:*?""<>|\r\n]*\\)?((?#file)[^\\/:*?""<>|\r\n]*))$"
bFound = RegEx.Test(Data)
```

Will match when the users have entered a VALID drive, folder, and filename.  Or, you use other iterations of the RegEx to test the matches.  Keep in mind, you do not have to check for "COM1:", "LPT1:", etc, because the RegEx will not allow colons in the path, except at the very start for the drive letter...

```
Dim RegEx
Set RegEx = New RegExp
RegEx.IgnoreCase = True
RegEx.Pattern = "\b((?#drive)[a-z]):\\((?#folder)[^/:*?""<>|\r\n]*\\)?((?#file)[^\\/:*?""<>|\r\n]*)"
If RegEx.Test(sFldrname ) Then
    ' Successful match
Else
    ' Match attempt failed
End If
```

Now, lets just say that you want to test for DOS Device names in the input from the user.  You can use a RegEx like the following to test for all combinations of COMn:, LPTn:, CON:, and NIL:.  This RegEx, of course, requires that the input START with COM, LPT, CON, etc, if the string does not start with it, lets, say, for example, they typed in a directory name of Wel**com**e, or heck, when Wel**COM3:** the RegEx would NOT match, indicating a clean path.  If you want it to be able to search the ENTIRE input string for the appearance of COM{n}:, then remove the \b out of the pattern...

```
Dim RegEx
Set RegEx = New RegExp
RegEx.IgnoreCase = True
RegEx.Pattern = "\b(COM[0-9]+|LPT[0-9]+|CON|NIL)\:"
If RegEx.Test(sFldrname ) Then
    ' We discovered a DOS Device name as a PATH, and it is therefore invalid.
End If
```

Now, to address your actual, QUESTION, you'll note the `RegEx.IGNORECASE = true`.  THAT is your ace in the hole there...

In my first example, I only showed you that as a lesson in how to do a case insensitive string comparison, something you will use OFTEN in writing just about any code in any language.  I'm showing you the OTHER examples as more of a "proper" way, or an "easier" way, or a more "assured" way to search for bad things in a path.  I think it's important that you look into something more solid, and much less code on your part, for a much more stable codebase.  Since you are dealing with PATHS, which, as you know, is a serious ability for someone to enter path names that can put them in the wrong folder, (for example, entering a folder name like `..\..\..\..\..\..\Windows\System32\` now, they end up with a folder created in Windows System32, and depending on what your app does, this can be a SERIOUS security risk.  So, don't just use the Regular Expressions I demonstrated.  You an employ tactics like FORCING the starting directory to be your programs home directory, and eating any periods,back-slashes, and any other "path" chars, and force the directory to be created under your home dir.  Hope this helps, sorry for the flood of data, but we've all been where you are!

Comment: I actually did use RegEx in another part of my code to make sure that illegal characters like : and \aren't used. I'm not too familiar with RegEx though and I couldn't figure out how to use it to make sure that the input isn't only the word COM1 for example. It is ok for COM1 to be part of the name as long as it isn't the entire name with nothing else.

Comment: I can get RegEx to recognize whether a piece of whatever pattern I specify is present in the user input so it is good for checking for a set of characters. But in the case of COM1, COM2, etc. I don't want it to just check for it's presence because its ok if its present. I want to be able to check if the input is just COM1 (case insensitive) and if so prevent it. So if the user entered COM1 it would be blocked but if the user entered ABCOM1 it would be allowed. The only way I've been able to figure out how to use RegEx both of those inputs would be blocked. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Sure.  Create a RegEx pattern, something like this, perhaps: "\b(COM[0-9]+|LPT[0-9]+|CON|NIL)\:" (without the quotes, or, actually, to assign them to the pattern, you'll need the quotes, but. you know...).  This will check for COMx: where x will be from 0 to ~4 billion, and same with LPT, and I threw CON: and NIL: in there, as those are also DOS device names that can cause havoc in paths for you. In my original answer, I was sort of getting at, that you should append the path they want to create, to where you are going to create it, then TEST the whole thing to make sure it's a valid path with

Comment: the RegEx I supplied.  Anyhow, look at the current Regex, and you'll see the \b?  That tells the RegEx matcher that this has to match at the BEGINNING of the string.  So, if they create a folder like welCOMe, the pattern will not match, telling you that the path supplied is good.  Also, I included the \: at the end?  That tells the matcher to match COM1:, not just COM1.  COM1 is a valid path, but COM1: isn't.  SOMEWHERE I dealt with this exact issue in a DLL, using RegEx.  If I dig up the code, I'll post it here for you.  Hope this helps man...

Comment: Thank you, it does help. The other RegEx I have in my script already checks for the presence of : and other illegal characters so something like COM1: would already not be allowed by that. Your current RegEx checks if the input begins with COM1 but it is ok if the folder name begins with COM1 as long as there's something else in the folder name so that the proposed folder name isn't just COM1. Is there a way to use RegEx to examine whether the input only consists of a string like COM1?

Comment: `\b` matches word boundaries, not the beginning of a string (that would be `^`). Also, `COM1` is [*not* a valid path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx), with or without the trailing colon. See also [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/10/22/55388.aspx) from Raymond Chen.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the input to uppercase, then compare to your uppercase forbidden string:

```
If uCase(sFldrname) = "COM1" Then
...
```

To avoid mistakes with the forbidden strings, uppercase them too:

```
If uCase(sFldrname) = uCase("COM1") Then
...
```