# I am new to vbscript and I am working on a basic yes no game is there a better way to write this?

Tags: optimization, vbscript

I am working on a basic yes no game right now as my first vbscript app and I am worried that there is a more efficient way to write this. My main concern is accounting for lowercase answers and at the end I have to write end end end end end etc, my current solution for multiple answers is writing more if statements but that makes my code longer and require a lot of ends at the final line of code

````
if a ="No" Then
p = MsgBox("Bye")
Else
if a ="no" Then
p1 = MsgBox("Bye")
Else
b = InputBox("What is your name?")
c = InputBox("Isn't that a good name?(Yes/No)")
if c ="No" Then
d = MsgBox("That's not nice.")
Else
if c ="no" Then
d1 = MsgBox("That's not nice.")
Else
l = MsgBox("It's good that you like it, afterall you are stuck with that name.")end if end if end if end if```
````

Comment: Use [Select Case](https://www.vbsedit.com/html/91c340af-8ceb-4f46-86fa-7871eefb3b01.asp).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I specify that the value of a variable in VBscript be case insensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26231600)

Comment: Asking "is there a better way to write this?" is something that should be asked on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) not [so]. See [Are code improvement questions allowed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349513)

Comment: Before you post at [codereview.se], make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it so that it isn't non-CaSe SeNsItIvE you can use the LCase or UCase function to make the inputted string either all upper case with UCase or fully lower case with LCase.

For your case you could do:

```
c = InputBox("Isn't that a good name?(Yes/No)")
if LCase(c) = "no" Then
   MsgBox("That's not nice.")
End If
```

No matter how the user capitalizes the input this will work.

To better visualize refer to this table:

| Input | LCase(input) |
| --- | --- |
| nO | no |
| No | no |
| no | no |

(Make sure that your = "`WHATEVER`" is either all in lowercase or uppercase depending if you use LCase or UCase as using the wrong case sensitivity from your function will not make it work)

Also, side note you don't need to make your MsgBox a variable.

Comment: This has already [been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26231600/692942) 8 years ago in greater detail.